# How can I prove a limit involving factorial of a log?

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms, factorial

Let's say that I wanted to prove the following problem which is *similar to a homework problem*. That is, the numerator and denominator are different, but similar enough that you posting an answer would likely give everything away.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{6n^4}{9\left \lfloor{\ln n}\right \rfloor!} = 0 $$

Using L'Hopitals rule does not help here (well, maybe), and factoring does not help either.

I am not sure where I could start. **I want to solve this myself so I can solve my homework problem.**

Is there anything obvious that jumps off the bat about this problem that I should be seeing? I come across stuff similar to this all of the time but never know where to start and I feel like I just get lucky after enough guesses, so I want to learn how to approach the problem.

Edit:

If it helps, I actually do not care that the **limit** is 0. I just care about which one grows faster as $n$ gets large and being able to prove that.

Comment: You understand that the factorial in the denominator in general is of an irrational number.

Comment: @Shailesh, isn't it the factorial of the floor function?

Comment: @yeldarbskich Sorry. I did not see the floor function

Answer (score 0):

Consider what happens
when you go from
$n$ to
$en$
in the numerator
and denominator.

Comment: Perhaps you meant $e^n$ ?

Comment: No. $\ln(ne) = \ln(n)+\ln(e) = \ln(n)+1$, so this increases what is in the $\lfloor \rfloor$ by one, so the next factorial will be computed.